# srcset responsive images inside multi column layout

Tags: html, multiple-columns, srcset

I have images inside an html article that is set to columns using a fixed column-width attribute on containing div.

I've added srcset for reponsive images which works fine except it loads the largest image based on the width of the containing div not a smaller image based on the width of the columns.

In some cases the article is displayed without columns so I was hoping the same image srcset can cater for both situations. Is there any way to make srcset select the smaller sized image when its showing the content in fixed with columns?

Comment: How was your code? Expecting here some code samples!

Comment: doesn't work srcset tag ignores multicolumn

Answer (score 0):

For lack of responses, I came up with wrapping div around the images so the div scales to the column and srcset picks image is selected based on the wrapper rather than the full div. If anyone has a better solution please share.

Update: Doesn't work as srcset looks at the viewport not the wrapping div. One way to solve this might be to just use 30vw in sizes if its in multicolumn or calculate the number of columns using the width of containing div and use that value as the vw amount in sizes.